# WPF mvvm binding, get/set value: issue with preventing update value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, setvalue

I'm working in a WPF mvvm environment.

I have some binded vars and data from cs file to xaml.

One is different from others: it is the index of the selected tab in my tabsCollection. When the user has more than one tab opened and has got mods to save, I show him a dialog. If he cliks "ok", he proceed with the change of the tab, if he clicks "cancel", the tab must remain the same.

this is my code:

```
private int p_SelectedDocumentIndex;
public int SelectedDocumentIndex{ get { return p_SelectedDocumentIndex; }
    set {
        if (tabsCollection.Count() > 1 && CanSave() == true)
        {
            if (dm.ShowMessage1(ServiceContainer.GetService<DevExpress.Mvvm.IDialogService>("confirmYesNo")))
            {
                p_SelectedDocumentIndex = value;
                base.RaisePropertiesChanged("SelectedDocumentIndex");
            }
            //else {
            //    CODE FOR NOT CHANGE THE VALUE 
            //}
        }
        else {
            p_SelectedDocumentIndex = value;
            base.RaisePropertiesChanged("SelectedDocumentIndex");
        }
    }
 }
```

So, the question is: how can I not apply the change in the "set" section? (like an undo, I think)

This  is simpliest way to do it, but, if this approach is incorrect, how can I do?

Previous failed attempts:

```
1)
p_SelectedDocumentIndex = p_SelectedDocumentIndex
base.RaisePropertiesChanged("SelectedDocumentIndex");

2)
base.RaisePropertiesChanged("SelectedDocumentIndex");

3)
nothing in the else branch
```

Comment: What does the following return? dm.ShowMessage1(ServiceContainer.GetService<DevExpress.Mvvm.IDialogService>("confirmYesNo"))

Comment: I said it in the question... it is an index. The index of the current active tab. When I change it, I show a dialog to the user. If he clicks on "cancel", I don't want to change the value, so I need to delete the new value and keep the previous.

Comment: I thought ShowMessage usaually returns a dialogResult and you have to check if the DialogResult is ok or cancel and then based on the dialogresult, you will be setting your private variable. Otherwise you wont set it so that the 'oldvalue' is retained

Comment: See if this helps you out - http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/how-to-prevent-a-tabitem-from-being-selected/.

Comment: @Krishna the dialog is fired by the changing of the value, not like you say, so I have this problem

Comment: @RohitVats unluckly no! :(

Comment: solved, look to my own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I've took the solution from here:

http://blog.alner.net/archive/2010/04/25/cancelling-selection-change-in-a-bound-wpf-combo-box.aspx

```
    public int SelectedDocumentIndex{ get { return p_SelectedDocumentIndex; }
        set {
            // Store the current value so that we can 
            // change it back if needed.
            var origValue = p_SelectedDocumentIndex;

            // If the value hasn't changed, don't do anything.
            if (value == p_SelectedDocumentIndex)
                return;

            // Note that we actually change the value for now.
            // This is necessary because WPF seems to query the 
            //  value after the change. The combo box
            // likes to know that the value did change.
            p_SelectedDocumentIndex = value;
            if (tabsCollection.Count() > 1 && CanSave() == true)
            {
                if (!dm.ShowMessage1(ServiceContainer.GetService<DevExpress.Mvvm.IDialogService>("confirmYesNo")))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Selection Cancelled.");

                    // change the value back, but do so after the 
                    // UI has finished it's current context operation.
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                            new Action(() =>
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine("Dispatcher BeginInvoke " + "Setting CurrentPersonCancellable.");

                                // Do this against the underlying value so 
                                //  that we don't invoke the cancellation question again.
                                p_SelectedDocumentIndex = origValue;
                                DocumentPanel p = tabsCollection.ElementAt(p_SelectedDocumentIndex);
                                p.IsActive = true;
                                base.RaisePropertiesChanged("SelectedDocumentIndex");
                            }),
                            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle,
                            null
                        );

                    // Exit early. 
                    return;
                }
            }
            // Normal path. Selection applied. 
            // Raise PropertyChanged on the field.
            Debug.WriteLine("Selection applied.");
            base.RaisePropertiesChanged("SelectedDocumentIndex");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => SelectedDocumentIndex= p_SelectedDocumentIndex ), DispatcherPriority.Send);
```

This call arranges to revert the UI state to where it was before the operation started

Answer (score 0):

If your VM class is derived from `DependencyObject` then you can change your property to a `DependecyProperty` with a coerce callback which enables "undo" as follows:

```
    public int SelectedDocumentIndex
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SelectedDocumentIndexProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedDocumentIndexProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDocumentIndexProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedDocumentIndex", typeof(int), typeof(MyViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(0,
            (d, e) =>
            {
                //Callback after value is changed
                var vm = (MyViewModel)d;
                var val = (int)e.NewValue;
            }, (d, v) =>
            {
                //Coerce before value is changed
                var vm = (MyViewModel)d;
                var val = (int)v;
                if (vm.tabsCollection.Count() > 1 && vm.CanSave() == true)
                {
                    if (vm.dm.ShowMessage1(ServiceContainer.GetService<DevExpress.Mvvm.IDialogService>("confirmYesNo")))
                    {
                        //no coerce is needed
                        return v;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //should coerce to the previous value
                        return VM.SelectedDocumentIndex;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //no coerce is needed
                    return v;
                }
            }));
```